# Why wont this code work on my website

Tags: jsfiddle

Im attempting to add this code to my website, built with sandvox, via the insert 'Raw HTML' function.  Once I add the code, I simply see a blank box on my site. Im hoping that there is some way I can get a bit of help. Thank you for any help.

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Prevalence of Performance Enhancing Drug Use By Sport'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://www.samuelwbennett.com">getfast</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Prevalence (%)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'PED Prevalence: <b>{point.y:.1f} %</b>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Prevalence',
            data: [
                ['WADA All Pros', 2],
                ['Child Athletes', 4],
                ['HS Football', 6.3],
                ['HS Seniors All Sports', 6.6],
                ['Amatuer Weight-lifters', 8.2],
                ['American Football', 9],
                ['Baseball', 9.4],
                ['Research Estimate All Pros', 10.2],
                ['Top 100 Sprinters (running)', 40],
                ['Professional Bodybuilders', 54],
                ['Tour de France Winners', 79],

            ],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                x: 4,
                y: -15,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});

 </hmtl>
```

Comment: what does the javascript console in the browser say?

Comment: You probably need to load `jQuery` before loading `highcharts`.

Comment: How do I add jquery before adding the highcharts?

Answer (score 0):

place jQuery script before highcharts js, and don't forget close your `<script>` tag

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Prevalence of Performance Enhancing Drug Use By Sport'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://www.samuelwbennett.com">getfast</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Prevalence (%)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'PED Prevalence: <b>{point.y:.1f} %</b>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Prevalence',
            data: [
                ['WADA All Pros', 2],
                ['Child Athletes', 4],
                ['HS Football', 6.3],
                ['HS Seniors All Sports', 6.6],
                ['Amatuer Weight-lifters', 8.2],
                ['American Football', 9],
                ['Baseball', 9.4],
                ['Research Estimate All Pros', 10.2],
                ['Top 100 Sprinters (running)', 40],
                ['Professional Bodybuilders', 54],
                ['Tour de France Winners', 79],

            ],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                x: 4,
                y: -15,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
</script>

</hmtl>
```

Comment: is there any error log message on console `F12` ? or can you share your site url here..

Comment: I've see your site, it seem you already have `jquery` plugin placed on footer,  so you load jquery twice, for now just move all script tag above (in my answer not your whole site) below your jQuery in footer, and remove jquery from this script, just use one on your site

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `</script>` tag at the end of your Highcharts script. Adding that closing tag and ensuring that jQuery is loaded before loading the Highcharts script should work great.

So it should be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <script>

       <!-- your Highcharts script here... -->

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

A working example can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8jft7z9c/1/).